# Which is better to use among ArrayList and LinkedHashMap for better speed if key/value datastructure is required

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I need to maintain key/value pairs. I need to maintain the insertion order also.  I know two approaches to do it:

Using ArrayList where each object would be of type entity containing key/value pairs as in ListData described below:

```
class ListData{

String key;
ArrayList<MyData> dataList;

}
```

Using LinkedHashMap for maintaing the key value pairs.

Is there any performance/speed problem in terms of speed in using LinkedHashMap?

Can someone suggest the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as performance is considered go for `LinkedHashMap` as `get(), put(), remove(). conyainsKey()` all are **O(1)** operations and your insertion order is retained. If you use `ArrayList` it will be **O(N)**.

Comment: thanks for the answer... LinkedHashMap should then fulfill my need

Answer (score 0):

No doubt Linked Hash Map is better in performance with comparison with ArrayList.I have doubt how you going to maintain Key/value pair in list.

But if you want to maintain key/value pair with ordering then go with `Linked Hash Map` otherwise `Hash Map`.